# Upstream dependency aware incremental build in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

The incremental build behavior in Jenkins seems to only build the following:

- [Previously failed modules](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-plugin/blob/maven-plugin-2.0/src/main/java/hudson/maven/MavenModuleSetBuild.java#L667)
- [Modules that has changes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/maven-plugin/blob/maven-plugin-2.0/src/main/java/hudson/maven/MavenModuleSetBuild.java#L684)

**My job chain**

```
Job A        --> Job B
Trunk A      --> Trunk B
- Module foo - - Module bar
                 - Module boo
```

Trunk B's module bar has a SNAPSHOT dependency of Trunk A's module foo. Both are configured with incremental build ticked.

**Problem**

Module foo and module boo have changes. Because incremental build is triggered, module bar is not built. Module bar is expected to be built as its dependency have a change.

Is there a way to configure Jenkins to build bar as well?