# Reducing redundant SNAPSHOTs

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

Our project currently have more than 500 SNAPSHOT jars to be downloaded daily. This is becoming a burden for development especially when Artifactory is in place remotely, hence the connection is not ideal.

I would like to know the best way to reduce redundant SNAPSHOTs jars that are deployed to Artifactory. We have a large multi-module project that is deploying almost 200 newly SNAPSHOT jars although there is actually only 1 module that contains changes.

I found a similar question [raised in the forum](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Reducing-SNAPSHOT-redundancy-td5692088.html) but no definite answer there too. Incremental build is not viable for us due to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614317/upstream-dependency-aware-incremental-build-in-jenkins).

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The "[Managing Disk Space Usage](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage)" page in the Artifactory wiki describes various methods for cleaning up old snapshots:

1. Limiting the Number of Snapshots - you can specify the maximum number of snapshots that may be stored. 
   To specify the maximum number of snapshots that may be stored, in the Edit Repository dialog, select the Basic Settings tab. You first need to check the Handle Snapshots checkbox which then enables you to set the Max Unique Snapshots field. This value is zero by default, which means that all snapshots are saved.
2. Using a user plugin for custom cleanup logic - you may write scripts to implement virtually any custom cleanup logic. This provides you with an extensive and flexible set of customization capabilities. See examples of such scripts on [Github](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup)

Comment: CMIIW but the "Unique" in Artifactory means every time I deploy the exact same SNAPSHOT jar, they will be considered unique right? Hence it is not solving my issue where the same binaries are re-deployed and re-downloaded over and over again.

Comment: Unique snapshots means that every new deployed snapshot will get a unique version (timestamp based). It does not really matter if it is the same as the previous one. By setting the max unique snapshot you limit the number of snapshots which will be kept. In addition, if two artifacts are binary identical (same checksum) Artifactory will keep the binary only once and have multiple pointers to it (checksum based storage). This is done to save disk space.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the disk space issue that we are trying to solve. Maven will determine whether or not a SNAPSHOT is new by checking the timestamp, not the checksum. The download will happen again, which is the problem that we are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If only one module changes, then why do you rebuild the entire project? Or in other words, your often changing module appears to have a different lifecycle than the rest of your project, so you should consider moving it to a separate project with its own release cycle.